# where is bundle file is stored in jasper directory?

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have created a properties file in jasper server and I have uploaded it on domain in local bundle. now I want to check it on jasper directory where this bundle file stored.can you please tell it from where we can check this in jasper directory?